# (Linux, julia dev version) Could not start the Julia language server. Make sure the `julia.executablePath` setting is valid

Tags: linux, julia

I'm trying to use the dev version of julia in linux (pop os), and I've set my `Julia: Executable Path` as

```
~/julia-1.9.0-beta4/bin/julia
```

but I get the following error

```
Could not start the Julia language server. Make sure the `julia.executablePath` setting is valid.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: you need to add `julia` to `PATH` as is discussed in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu and I ran into this same issue. After installing Julia I ran the `julia` command at the command line and it pulled up the Julia terminal. So I knew Julia was already on my path. You can also run `nano ~/.bashrc` and check if there is an entry for Julia on your path.

To get my executable path I typed `which julia` at the command line, which returned `/home/<my-user-name>/.juliaup/bin/julia`. That is the executable path that worked for me.

In VSCode I clicked "File" >> "Preferences" >> "Settings" and entered `julia.executablePath` into the "Search settings" field. That pulled up the **Julia: Executable Path** setting. I entered `~/.juliaup/bin/julia` into the **Julia: Executable Path** field and it worked.